# How allow anonymous access to IBM MQ Queue

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm new in IBM MQ so sorry for my "stupid" question.
I have installed IBM MQ on Ubuntu server. I've created a queue manager, channel and want to connect from MQ Explorer (on Windows) to this installed IBM MQ and get this error : AMQ 4036. 
How allow any anonymous connection to my query?
I don't want create some user that allow connect to queue

UPD.
I'm trying do this:
`set chlauth(DQUE) type(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST (ALLOWANY)` - didnt help

UPD 2 :
in AMQERR01.LOG

```
11/06/19 09:21:38 - Process(436.10) User(root) Program(amqrmppa) Host(e87cc2388cc1) Installation(Installation1) VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(DQUE)

AMQ9557: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'hsa'.

EXPLANATION:

The call to initialize the User ID 'hsa' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason 2035.

ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
```

Comment: i`m try do this - setmqaut -m DQUE -t qmgr -g mqm +all  - didnt help

Comment: That would give permission to users in the `mqm` group which by default already have full access, any member of the `mqm` group is an Admin user.  What error shows up in  `/var/mqm/qmgrs/DQUE/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` when you connect?  Please click edit and add the details to the question not a comment

Comment: in AMQERR01.LOG ` 11/06/19 09:21:38 - Process(436.10) User(root) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(e87cc2388cc1) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(DQUE)

AMQ9557: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'hsa'.

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID 'hsa' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason
2035.
ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
`

Comment: i`m try do this: set chlauth(DQUE) type(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST (ALLOWANY) - didnt help.

Comment: Please as requested, click edit under your question and add the details.

Comment: Do you know how to edit?

Comment: Is it possible that your user id 'hsa' is not known on the server where the queue manager is running?

Comment: yes, this is my Windows user and not in MQ server.

Comment: Please add the AMQERR01.LOG entry to your question.

Comment: The most secure option would be to configure MQ Explorer to pass a username and password that exists on the Linux system.  You can configure the queue manager to force authentication on the channel with `CHKCLNT(REQUIRED)`.  In this way it does not matter what user exists on the windows machine since you specifically pass a user that is a valid Linux user.

Comment: so i`m just need create some linux user with password  and configure MQ Explorer to use this user ?